# How to append geojson file using featureselection

Tags: python, geojson, json, matplotlib

For example, I have a file as shown below:

> {   "type": "FeatureCollection",   "features": [
>       {
>         "type": "Feature",
>         "properties": {},
>         "geometry": {
>           "type": "LineString",
>           "coordinates": [
>             [
>               8.2781982421875,
>               52.58636344214018
>             ],
>             [
>               10.0250244140625,
>               52.281601868071434
>             ],
>             [
>               8.865966796875,
>               52.07612995654167
>             ],
>             [
>               8.519897460937498,
>               52.24125614966341
>             ]
>           ]
>         }
>       }   ] }

and I want to update this file get something like this.

> {   "type": "FeatureCollection",   "features": [
>       {
>         "type": "Feature",
>         "properties": {},
>         "geometry": {
>           "type": "LineString",
>           "coordinates": [
>             [
>               8.2781982421875,
>               52.58636344214018
>             ],
>             [
>               10.0250244140625,
>               52.281601868071434
>             ],
>             [
>               8.865966796875,
>               52.07612995654167
>             ],
>             [
>               8.519897460937498,
>               52.24125614966341
>             ]
>           ]
>         }
>       },
>       {
>         "type": "Feature",
>         "properties": {},
>         "geometry": {
>           "type": "LineString",
>           "coordinates": [
>             [
>               8.10791015625,
>               51.580483198305345
>             ],
>             [
>               7.6629638671875,
>               52.05249047600099
>             ],
>             [
>               7.717895507812499,
>               52.36553758871974
>             ],
>             [
>               8.0584716796875,
>               52.09638241034154
>             ],
>             [
>               8.1793212890625,
>               51.71681946274873
>             ]
>           ]
>         }
>       }   ] }

How to append this geojson file?

Comment: Are you working with any sort of module? Or just the built in Python JSON module? And this is essentially just a dictionary?

Comment: Yes, I am working on geoplotlib. Currently my code is appending in the end which is problem while parsing rather ( as shown below )  i just want to update features in the existent file.

Comment: { "type": "FeatureCollection", "features": [ { "type": "Feature", "properties": {}, "geometry": { "type": "LineString", "coordinates": [ [ 8.2781982421875, 52.58636344214018 ], [ 10.0250244140625, 52.281601868071434 ], [ 8.865966796875, 52.07612995654167 ], [ 8.519897460937498, 52.24125614966341 ] ] } } ] }{ "type": "FeatureCollection", "features": [ { "type": "Feature", "properties": {}, "geometry": { "type": "LineString", "coordinates": [ [ 8.10791015625, 51.580483198305345 ], [ 7.6629638671875, 52.05249047600099 ], ............  } } ] }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know the `geoplotlib` library; perhaps it has a built in function to make this "Easy".
However, because you can display JSON as a python dictionary, you can just add to it using the built in dictionary and list functions.

Take your first bit of JSON:

```
z = { "type": "FeatureCollection", "features": [ { "type": "Feature", "properties": {}, "geometry": { "type": "LineString", "coordinates": [ [ 8.2781982421875, 52.58636344214018 ], [ 10.0250244140625, 52.281601868071434 ], [ 8.865966796875, 52.07612995654167 ], [ 8.519897460937498, 52.24125614966341 ] ] } } ] }
```

You can then display just the `features` (the list you want to update):

```
z['features']
```

I assume you have your feature you want to add somewhere, say, as a variable?

```
newfeats =  { "type": "Feature", "properties": {}, "geometry": { "type": "LineString", "coordinates": [ [ 8.10791015625, 51.580483198305345 ], [ 7.6629638671875, 52.05249047600099 ], [ 7.717895507812499, 52.36553758871974 ], [ 8.0584716796875, 52.09638241034154 ], [ 8.1793212890625, 51.71681946274873 ] ] } }
```

You just need to append your new feature dictionary to the feature list:

```
z['features'].append(newfeat)
```

There you go:

```
z['features']
```

> [{'geometry': {'type': 'LineString', 'coordinates': [[8.2781982421875,
>   52.58636344214018], [10.0250244140625, 52.281601868071434], [8.865966796875, 52.07612995654167], [8.519897460937498,
>   52.24125614966341]]}, 'type': 'Feature', 'properties': {}}, {'geometry': {'type': 'LineString', 'coordinates': [[8.10791015625,
>   51.580483198305345], [7.6629638671875, 52.05249047600099], [7.717895507812499, 52.36553758871974], [8.0584716796875,
>   52.09638241034154], [8.1793212890625, 51.71681946274873]]}, 'type': 'Feature', 'properties': {}}]